# Completion of Measure Space

Tags: probability, measure-theory

A measure $\mu$ on a $\sigma$-field $\sigma(F)$ is said to be complete IFF whenever $A\in \sigma(F)$ and $\mu(A)=0$, we have $B\in\sigma(F)$ for all $B\subset A$.

My Question: What is the intuition behind this DEFINITION? If you have a set of pebbles that has a negligible measure, any subset of pepples in that set must be in the sigma-field? Why does this have to do with the concept of "completeness"?

Comment: Good question. The problem is the following: subsets of measurable sets do not necessarily remain measurable. It is for this reason that the Lebesgue measure is not complete on the Borel sets but one often looks at the completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is just a definition.

I do not think it has something to do with the completeness of a metric space for instance.

> Now there are cases in some sigma algebras where we have a set $A$ in the sigma algebra with $\mu(A)=0$ and $V \subseteq A$ such that $V$ is not in the sigma algebra.

Take for instance the Borel sigma algebra on $\Bbb{R}^d,d \geq 1$ with the Lebesgue measure.

There are sets with zero measure that have subsets that are not Borel measureable.

The completion of the Borel sigma algebra,is the sigma algebra $\mathcal{M}$ of Lebesgue measurable sets.

With the  completion and the appropriate theorem, we can extend the sigma algebra in order to contain all those
''negligible'' sets described in the pink.